# Open CV video capture doesn't print the frame and values are all zeroes and output is black screen

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

```
import cv2

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(frame)
    print(frame.sum())
else:
    ret = False

img1 = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.imshow(img1)
plt.title('Color Image RGB')
plt.show()

cap.release()
```

***I get output as ***

> print(frame) --> [[[0 0 0]....[0 0 0]]]
>
> print(frame.sum() --> 0
>
> plt.show --> gives a black screen

This is what output image looks like:

[image: output image]

Comment: Your code is Ok. It looks like you have some problem with the capture device.

Comment: The code works for me, you might have more than one capturing device and the frame is captured from a different device than you intended.

Comment: I work on my laptop and besides that when I turn on the camera app, it runs properly. I'm totally unsure what's wrong 